# svn $Rev$ - Obtain just the revision numbers

Tags: svn

Is it possible to trim the output from $Rev$

When committing a file the variable is changed to "$Rev: 1234 $" but I would just like to retrieve just the 1234.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible by post-processing the file with a non-SVN tool (usually part of your build/release process).

Consider this: If you remove the full marker, how will the Subversion client know to perform the keyword substitution on the next update?

The Subversion client, when it finds a file marked with the `svn:keywords` property, scans the file contents for that keyword and performs the substitution. If you strip it out and leave just the revision number, the client not find the keyword and will be unable to update the revision number in the file.